# Bash script "read" not pausing for user input when executed from SSH shell

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I'm new to Bash scripting, so please be gentle.

I'm connected to a Ubuntu server via SSH (PuTTY) and when I run this command, I expect the bash script that downloads and executes to allow user input and then echo that input.  It seems to just write out the echo label for the input request and terminate.

```
wget -O - https://raw.github.com/aaronhancock/pub/master/bash/readtest.sh | bash
```

Any clue what I might be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** This bash command does exactly what I wanted

```
bash <(wget -q -O - https://raw.github.com/aaronhancock/pub/master/bash/readtest.sh)
```

Comment: There is no need to update the _question_ with the contents of the _answer_. The accepted answer is  visible below anyway.

Comment: My update was slightly different than the accepted answer below, so I thought I would share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan already mentioned: `bash` takes its stdin from the pipe.
And therefore you cannot pipe the script into `bash` when you want to interactively input something. But you could use the *process substitution* feature of `bash` (assumed your login shell is a `bash`):

```
bash <(wget -O - https://raw.github.com/aaronhancock/pub/master/bash/readtest.sh)
```

Comment: Or just wget to a file and _then_ execute. No need for rocket science, I would say.

Answer (score 0):

Bash is taking stdin from the pipe, not from the terminal.  So you can't pipe a script to bash and still use the "read" command for user input.

Notice that you have the same problem if you save the script to a local file and pipe it to bash:

```
less readtest.sh | bash
```

Comment: Jonathan, is there a way to get user input from the bash script through SSH then?

Answer (score 0):

I found this also works and helps keep the data in the current scope.

eval "`wget -q -O - https://raw.github.com/aaronhancock/pub/master/bash/readtest.sh`"